# Knockoutjs: the $data in foreach binding is not updating underlying element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have below js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = {
        predefinedGrades: [
            ko.observable("Excellent"),
            ko.observable("Good"),
            ko.observable("OK"),
            ko.observable("Average"),
            ko.observable("Bad")],
        observable: ko.observable("good")
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Below is my view

```
<div data-bind="foreach: predefinedGrades">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
</div>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: observable, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
```

The problem is that when I update the text in the input of `foreach` binding, the underlying array won't change. But if I change the text with the last text input of the binding `observable`, the observable field can change after keyup event. How so? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `$rawData` instead of `$data` in your `foreach` binding, it will work as expected.

[**From the docs**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

> $rawData
>
> This is the raw view model value in the current context. Usually this
>   will be the same as $data, but if the view model provided to Knockout
>   is wrapped in an observable, $data will be the unwrapped view model,
>   and $rawData will be the observable itself.

Comment: Just note that this was added in Knockout 3.0. In previous versions, you have to use other approaches to gain access to the underlying observable.